# Anyone who knows fine neural network code or module for python?

Tags: matlab, python, neural-network

I want to change my main platform from Matlab to Python due to my work, and I mainly used Matlab for the neural network, so I want to do the same thing in the Python either.

I used to make my own network architecture like the picture below.
[image]

I wanted to replicate this network in Python either, but I can't find the module which can adjust the input connection and layer connection so far.
As far as I know, 'neurolab' and 'sklearn' doesn't provide the function what I said. Every code I found connect input data to the first layer.

So, anybody who knows the module or code which can make network architecture like the attached picture, please help me.

Comment: I am not sure that this is the best stackexchange for this question, anyway Do you see [Keras](https://keras.io/)? I think is one of the best module for neural network in python.

Answer (score 1):

A very flexible Python library you could use to build your network and perform the various Machine Learning operations is Tensorflow. The premise of this library is you construct graphs that you can use to represent models, perform computation, and many other things. Using this framework, you can build arbitrary neural network models, amongst other things.

Note that this framework does have a little bit of a learning curve, though.